# An -e option to cd builtin

Tags: bash, cd-command, shell-builtin

According to Bash reference on Bash builtins:

> `cd [-L|[-P [-e]]] [directory]`
>
> The -P option means to not follow symbolic links; symbolic links are
>   followed by default or with the -L option. If the -e option is
>   supplied with -P and the current working directory cannot be
>   successfully determined after a successful directory change, cd will
>   return an unsuccessful status.

Can somebody give me an example of situation when `-e` is useful?

Right now, if I supply -P option with -e (`cd -P -e`), I'm getting a usage message along with an error telling me that -e is "invalid option". Why is that?

Comment: The `-e` option was introduced in bash 4.2. What version are you running?

Comment: GNU bash, version 4.2.37(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug, it will be fixed in the next release. You can see the response to this bug [here](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2013-01/msg00099.html).